# Deezer employee writing low quality answers to Deezer questions

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I came across this at random but we seem to have a tag [deezer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deezer) that seems to be being used as tech support for the Deezer music API.

I can't see anything official on the Deezer web pointing them at SO but it seems to me to be riddled with poor quality questions:

- [Deezer API - Special Album
  Editions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46385645/deezer-api-special-album-editions) {10k+)
- [deezer Flow API
  Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41817617/deezer-flow-api-support) (10k+)
- [Work around Deezer
  baseURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45930329/work-around-deezer-baseurl) (10k+)
- [Deezer API - Pull List of Playlists That Contain a
  Track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555035/deezer-api-pull-list-of-playlists-that-contain-a-track) (10k+)

Lots of these questions appear to have low quality answers by **one user [fred-dzr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3790974/fred-dzr)** many of which just point at the Deezer web site. From reading some of the answers it appears that fred-dzr works for Deezer (his answers talk about Deezer in the first person "We don't do this", etc.) and the company seem to be using SO as some kind of unofficial technical support forum. I've also just noticed his profile states [*Developer @Deezer*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3790974/fred-dzr) so it appears he is an employee.

Is this OK? Has Deezer contacted SO about this?

I suppose **there's not a huge amount of issue with Deezer employees (whatever) answering questions about their service** but many of this guy's answers are pretty questionable and often just point the OP at the Deezer web site.

I feel like someone needs to reach out to either this guy or Deezer themselves to get them to improve this. As it stands **a lot of these answers (IMO) should be flagged as low quality and many of the questions should be closed**. I've not done this to date because there are just so many.

Example poor answers includes

> All the information related to the Flow in our REST API are here:
>   http://developers.deezer.com/api/user/flow

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41834462/542251

> Actually, developers.deezer.com/guidelines#content-access explains our
>   guidelines for our apps. As you are using our Javacript SDK, the rules
>   that are applied are available here, at the section "FAQ":
>   https://developers.deezer.com/musicplugins/player

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45794455/542251

> The only way to play a full track is by using our SDKs available here:
>   http://developers.deezer.com
>
> There is no possibility to retrieve the MP3 URL.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43865472/542251

It seems according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46311453/deezer-authentication-failed-with-invalid-oauth-access-token-error) that Deezer are indeed sending people to SO for development support:

> Sent to stackoverflow from Deezer dev support website

Comment: Too many sites do this. It's frustrating when you tell the asker that it's not ontopic here, only to be met with "but they told me to ask here". At least deezer appears to have a representative kinda sorta dealing with the questions, but no, they shouldn't be here in the first place.

Comment: Programming questions relating to the use of an external API *are* on-topic so long as they can be answered by anyone familiar with that API and not just the API vendor (and aren't off-topic for any other reason), it's just that the answers being given are poor and the questions - the on-topic ones - deserve better.

Comment: Yes, my point exactly @BoltClock sure answer the questions, but give good answers that stick to the general guidelines about link only, etc. I was going to flag as low quality but there we're too many.

Comment: @Liam: As mentioned by Walfrat, the original title of your question implied something else.

Comment: We can't stop companies doing this, no. They don't have to ask permission either. We *do* try to help companies by providing information; otherwise their users will have a rotten experience, which is usually not what such companies want. See [How can I use Stack Overflow to support our developer community?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326374) for the advice given.

Comment: I suppose this boils down to, rather than flag all the low quality answers it'd be more efficient (IMO) if a mod or someone else, approaches this guy (deezer in general) and says, *"look we don't have a big problem with you doing this but can you please make sure you stick to the rules."*. This is basically what I'm asking. The other side of the coin is, if the answer is *"flag the low quality posts"*, then fine. I just want some advice. Apologies is this isn't hasn't been that clear.

Comment: The usual response to these kind of queries is: flag for moderator attention on one of the answers and explain the situation there. A user posting low/very low quality answers is not great but it can be dealt with. Directly exposing such a user in a meta post like this and putting them in the public eye is not really a nice thing to do.

Comment: As with anything, if you see a bad answer, just downvote it and move on. If everyone did that, the user would get post banned and it would stop or cause them to figure out how to post better answers (which is ultimately what we want)

Comment: Hello Liam,

Nice to meet you! You're right, I work at Deezer, and we try to answer to some questions tagged with the label "deezer".

I just would want to point out that our Official Support for our APIs and SDKs is not Stack Overflow but our website and the contact email provided. People on SO are just asking for some questions, and most of the answers are available on our developers website, that's why we redirect them to it. 

I'm sorry if there is a misunderstanding about that, and we will be happy to follow the advises available at the link mentioned above.

Comment: Hi @Fred_Dzr. Great thanks for the response. I have no objection to Deezer answering questions here but we do need to ensure that the answers (and the **questions**!) meet our minimum requirements as designated in the [help]

Answer (score -4):

I don't think that we can say that Deezer is using SO as a support because one of their developpers answer to deezer's question. 
A lot of people just ask anything about development here without knowing if there is even a community to answer to those questions.

It may be someone with good faith that just browse common platforms to help people with deezer stuff and that don't consider SO as different than quora or whatever.

As I see, 2 of you three links (1st & 3rd) should be closed for low quality as you said IMO, however the second is perfectly on-topic. Proprietary API aren't excluded on SO.

My interpretation of what we mean we say that we're not the support tools of platforms is more about excluding everything that isn't related strictly programming for a platform :

- How do I install the platform
- How do I get a licence
- ...

And that we absolutely don't have any obligations to solve the problem of the user if no one know here even if it is on-topic.

As for the poor content of the user, did you try to tell him with some comments first ?

Comment: Like I said, asking the questions and answering them is fine, but most of this persons answers are low quality. I could flag all of his answers but this didn't seem practical. He also states in his profile that he works for Deezer.

Comment: You could ping him with  a comment ? Or you could ask a moderator for attention so he can deal with the user (they do that, but they would expect that you did try before contacting them). Note that I answered based on both the content of your post and the title, I interpreted your title as a reference of the "SO is not your [customer] tech support" rule. I answered based on that because as state like this your question is a bit confusing. Are we ok to answers question about proprietary API ? Yes, for the rest the same rule applieslike for every questions.